# how to concatenate styles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, vue.js

*I think the error is in this part, sorry I'm new to react*

**`{styles.navbar navbar-default}`**

> this is my code

```
import styles from './Header.scss';

class Header extends Component {

render() { return (
  <nav className={styles.navbar navbar-default}>

  </nav>
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnjJj.png)

Comment: So, What is the error? adding more details about your question will help you get better answer.:)

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mcqmr9

Comment: @V1P3R Check the updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to be

```
<nav className={styles.navbar,styles.navbar-default}></nav>
```

Or you can also try this. In this case the second property will override same style property in `styles.navbar`

```
<nav className=style={Object.assign({}, styles.navbar, styles.navbar-default)}></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a scss as below

```
export default {
     navbar: "navbar-default"
}
```

Assuming you have used named/default export from your scss file, you have to use the variables from file as below:

```
import styles from './Header.scss';

class Header extends Component {
render() { return (
  <nav className={styles.navbar}>
  </nav>
    );
  }
}
```